# Send [box-shadow] to the same place as [css-box-shadow]

Tags: support, tags, synonym-request

There is a fairly-recent [box-shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/box-shadow) tag, which is for the CSS `box-shadow` property. Now, previously there was a [css-box-shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-box-shadow) which is now a synonym for [css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3), so it seems logical the same thing should also happen for this tag.

Normally I would propose this tag as a synonym, but since [css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3) is considered a version specific synonym, I don't have the ability to do so.

[image: version specific synonyms error]

So to clarify, I propose that [box-shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/box-shadow) be made a synonym for [css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3), just like [css-box-shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-box-shadow) currently is.

Comment: It seems people really care about having a separate box-shadow tag. I wonder why...